# Token not getting empty after logout swift

Tags: ios, swift, token, django-rest-auth

i have a swift application which uses API for authentication everything works fine and when users logout, the login token is supposed to get cleared so that the new user's details can be collected and the new Token passed into the header but i noticed that when I try login in another user, the previous users token remains in the header and thereby preventing the new user from login in. I clear the login values on logout button pressed but i have no idea why the token value remains in the header. my codes are shown below

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

var isLoggedIn : Bool {

    get {
        return defaults.bool(forKey: LOGGED_IN_KEY)
    }
    set {
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: LOGGED_IN_KEY)
    }
}

var authToken: String {
    get {
        return defaults.value(forKey: TOKEN_KEY) as? String ?? ""
    }
    set {
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: TOKEN_KEY)
    }
}

var userUsername: String {
    get {
        return defaults.value(forKey: USER_USERNAME) as? String ?? ""
    }
    set {
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: USER_USERNAME)
    }
}
//MARK :- LOGGIN
func findUserByUserName(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_BY_USERNAME, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: TOKEN_HEADER).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        print("URL USER BY HEADER \(self.authToken)")

        if response.result.error == nil {

            guard let data = response.data else {return}
            let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print(jsonString as Any)
            self.setUserInfo(data: data)

            completion(true)
            }
         else {


            completion(false)
            debugPrint("ERROR 22222\(response.result.error as Any)")
        }
    }
}


func setUserInfo(data: Data) -> Void {
    do {
        let json = try JSON(data: data)
        let pk = json["pk"].intValue
        let username = json["username"].stringValue
        let email = json["email"].stringValue
        let firstName = json["first_name"].stringValue
        let lastName = json["last_nameme"].stringValue

        print("THE USERNAME IZZZZ \(username)")

        UserDataService.instance.setUserData(pk: pk, username: username, email: email, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

func loginUser(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

    let usernameEmail = email.lowercased()

    let body: [String: Any] = [
        "username": usernameEmail,
        "email": "",
        "password": password,
    ]

    Alamofire.request(URL_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.error == nil {
            print("LOGIN SUCCESFULL \(self.authToken)")

            do {


                guard let data = response.data else {return}
                let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("HELLOOO \(jsonString as Any)")
                let json = try JSON(data: data)
                self.authToken = json["key"].stringValue
                self.userUsername = email



                self.isLoggedIn = true

                completion(true)
                print("LOGIN SUCCESFULL TOKEN1111 \(self.authToken)")

            } catch {
                print("errorrrrr")
            }

        } else {
            completion(false)
            debugPrint("ERROR YENNNNN \(response.result.error as Any)")
        }
    }
}


//MARK :- LOGGIN
func findUserByEmail(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

    let body: [String: Any] = [
        "username": AuthService.instance.userUsername,

        ]

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_BY_EMAIL, method: .put, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: TOKEN_HEADER).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        print("URL USER BY HEADER \(self.authToken)")

        if response.result.error == nil {

            guard let data = response.data else {return}
            print("USERUSERNAME \(self.authToken)")
            let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print(jsonString as Any)
            self.setUserInfo(data: data)

            completion(true)
            }
         else {


            completion(false)
            debugPrint("ERROR 22222\(response.result.error as Any)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Token Constant**

```
let TOKEN_HEADER = [
    "Authorization": "Token \(AuthService.instance.authToken)",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
]
```

**UserService**

```
func setUserData(pk: Int, username: String, email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String) -> Void {

    self.pk = pk
    self.username = username
    self.email = email
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
}


func logoutUser() -> Void {
    self.pk = 0
    self.username = ""
    self.email = ""
    self.firstName = ""
    self.lastName = ""
    AuthService.instance.isLoggedIn = false
    AuthService.instance.authToken = ""
    AuthService.instance.userUsername = ""
}
```

**Logout**

```
@IBAction func logoutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDataService.instance.logoutUser()
        print("LOGOUT TOKEN \(AuthService.instance.authToken)")
        UserDataService.instance.setUserData(pk: 0, username: "", email: "", firstName: "", lastName: "")
        AuthService.instance.authToken = ""
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NOTIFY_USER_DATA_DID_CHANGE, object: nil)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

further codes would be supplied on request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you think that whenever you call `TOKEN_HEADER` you get the lastest value from

```
 let TOKEN_HEADER = [
   "Authorization": "Token \(AuthService.instance.authToken)",
   "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
 ]
```

but this doesn't happen as the variable get it's value from first initialization whatever the token value was , so you have to refactor sending the the header to `Alamofire`  , by hardcoding the string again like this

```
func findUserByUserName(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

   let updated_HEADER = [
   "Authorization": "Token \(AuthService.instance.authToken)",
   "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  ]

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_BY_USERNAME, 
    method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
    headers:updated_HEADER).validate().responseJSON { (response) in }

}
```

Comment: so how do I change the variable to reflect the new variable

Comment: init it again inside the method see answer , BTW make it local for every Alamofire request as it should be updated to reflect the last value

Comment: it is not possible to pass both token into the alamofire. I dont understand your solution please explain further

Comment: You will only pass one token the updated see edit .......... the idea is that we create another var inside the method to grap the lastest value as the outer one **TOKEN_HEADER** won't change whenever the token changed so remove it completely from the app

Comment: Thanks so much. This saved me a lot of time. I am very grateful. I have a lot of bugs with the application and I do not know if you don't mind i send the link of the other asked question

Comment: I’m a junior Developer and it would be a pleasure to communicate with you and pick you as a mentor 